# What does it really mean AfterWatermark.withEarlyFirings?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We understand the [withLateFirings](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/AfterWatermark.AfterWatermarkEarly.html#withLateFirings-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.windowing.Trigger.OnceTrigger-) from the example mentioned in the [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-dataflow-nyc-taxi-tycoon/#10). What does it really mean about [withEarlyFirings](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/AfterWatermark.AfterWatermarkLate.html#withEarlyFirings-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.windowing.Trigger.OnceTrigger-)?

Answer (score 0):

It may be worthwhile reading related data on windowing in dataflow. A sliding time window also uses time intervals in the data stream to define bundles of data; however, with sliding time windowing, the windows overlap. Each window might capture five minutes worth of data, but a new window starts every ten seconds. The frequency with which sliding windows begin is called the period. 
More detail can be gathered from the "Windowing" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/windowing), "Sliding Time Windows" sub-chapter.

Answer (score 0):

The watermark is the system’s notion of when all the events for that window should have arrived. Early firings allow to emit early speculative results before the watermark.

A very interesting example with animations can be found in [this article](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-102). For example, the following code snippet provides early updates each minute:

```
PCollection<KV<String, Integer>> scores = input
  .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(2)))
               .triggering(
                 AtWatermark()
                   .withEarlyFirings(AtPeriod(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
                   .withLateFirings(AtCount(1))))
  .apply(Sum.integersPerKey());
```

If you want to play around with that you can also get the timing of each fired pane with getTiming(). [PaneInfo docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/PaneInfo.html)

```
@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
    String timing  = c.pane().getTiming().toString());
    ...
}
```